# Find the best parallel lines to a given data set

Tags: programming

I have a set of data in an uptrend. I would like to find two BEST parallel lines 
to contain all the data but I don't know how to approach it, anyone can help ? Thanks.

[image: find parallel lines]

Comment: Please provide the data to work on. Is this homework?

Comment: Hi, yes, it is a programming problem from college project. i just randomly pick some data to show what my problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the policy about homeworks but this might be usefull so I suspect it will not be deleted. However it is also good to provide the data set, even randomly generated, it will focus more attention. Moreover it may be important, here for example we do not know if we have to work on list of values or list of points.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem is not directly related to college project, but I come up with something and wanted to prove it using programming but I stuck here. Yes, I can share the data but it is my a newbie here so I don't know how to upload my sample data.

Comment: thanks all, but I am not very familiar with matlab and I may take a while to understand your coding.

Comment: You don't have to because it is about Mathematica :)

Comment: A solution with Mathematica, or any other CAS, will give you answer but not insight, which is what you want as student. For this, have a look at Support Vector Machine in wikipedia; it  is a very similar problem you can solve using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Do you realize that you posted your question on a Q&A site for the Mathematica programming environment?

Comment: Sorry, no, i just figured out....

Comment: That happens a lot. Just look up convex hull algorithms and implement one in the language of your choice. Don't try to hand in somebody else's implementation for your own. They'll know. Good luck in college!

Comment: Actually, this is precisely a linear programming problem. Of course, it has only three variables (and only one of them is "interesting"), so really simple things work well.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Depends on the number of data points. If you have 10^6 or 10^7 points, really simple things might take some time ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a computational geometry problem. I'll illustrate a solution using some sample data:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
pts = Table[{x, Sin[x*3] + x/2. + RandomReal[.5]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

You want to find 3 "support points" in your data, that touch these two lines. Now imagine you had a "convex hull", i.e. the smallest convex polygon that contains all your data points. Calculating a convex hull is cheap (at least in 2D) and it eliminates most of the points in your data:

```
hull = ConvexHull[pts];

ListPlot[pts, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts[[hull]]], Opacity[0.2], 
   Line[pts[[Append[hull, hull[[1]]]]]]}]
```

[image]

Obviously, the support points you're looking for are all on the convex hull. And two of them are next to each other on the convex hull.

**EDIT**: I'll shamelessly copy @Kuba's idea to minimize `m` first, as it makes the solution so much simpler:

```
(* find the possible value for m - the slopes between each adjacent \
pair of points on the convex hull *)
possibleMs = 
  Divide @@@ Differences[Reverse /@ pts[[Append[hull, hull[[1]]]]]];
(* find the m with the smallest c2-c1 difference *)
m = SortBy[possibleMs, Max[#] - Min[#] &[pts[[hull]].{-#, 1}] &][[1]];
(* find c1 and c2 *)
{c1, c2} = {Max[#], Min[#]} &[pts[[hull]].{-m, 1}];

ListPlot[pts, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, Line[{{0, c1}, {10, 10 m + c1}}], 
   Line[{{0, c2}, {10, 10 m + c2}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Solution with `NMinimize`:

```
data = Table[Sin[15 x] + 3 x + RandomReal[] + 5, {x, 0, 1, .005}];

ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

The basic idea is to reduce the data so that lines we are looking for are going to be parallel to OX axis with (data - `m ran`). Then `Max-Min` value of such data set is the exactly equal to `|c1-c2|`.

```
ran = Range[1, Length@data];
ClearAll[m];
sol = NMinimize[Max[#] - Min[#] &[data - (m ran)], m]
```

> ```
> {2.86863, {m -> 0.0152302}}
> ```

```
{a, c1, c2} = {m, Max[#], Min[#]} &[data - (m ran)] /. sol[[ 2]]
```

> ```
> {0.0152302, 6.84349, 3.97486}
> ```

```
Plot[{a x + c1, a x + c2}, {x, 0, 200}, Epilog -> Point[Transpose[{ran, data}]]]
```

[image]

---

Just another data set:

```
data = Table[Sin[x/10]/(x/200) + x/50 + RandomReal[] + 5, {x, 50, 200}];
(*calculations*)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easy, no brain used, direct approach:

```
pts = Table[{x, Sin[x*3] + x/2. + RandomReal[.5]}, {x, 0,  10, .1}]; 
sol = Minimize[{c2 - c1, 
                And @@ (m #[[1]] + c1 <= #[[2]] <= (m #[[1]] + c2) & /@ pts)}, 
                {c1, c2, m}]


Show[Plot[{(m x + c1), (m x + c2)} /. sol[[2]], {x, 0, 10}], ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With the other Kuba's example:

```
pts = Table[{x, Sin[x/10]/(x/200) + x/50 + RandomReal[] + 5}, {x, 50,  200}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

If you want to minimize the **distance** between the two lines, the results are slightly different:

```
pts = Table[{x, Sin[x/10]/(x/200) + x/50 + RandomReal[] + 5}, {x, 50, 200}];
sol = Quiet@ NMinimize[{Abs[(c2 - c1)] Cos[ArcTan[m]], 
                       m > 0 && 
                       FullSimplify[ And @@ (m #[[1]] + c1 <= #[[2]] <= (m #[[1]] + c2) & /@ pts)]}, 
                       {c1, c2, m}]
Show[Plot[{(m x + c1), (m x + c2)} /. sol[[2]], {x, 0, 200}], ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]